# Convert ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to List<List<String>> - Java

Tags: java

I have a function that has to output a `List<List<String>>`

```
public List<List<String>> suggestedProducts(String[] products, String searchWord)
```

However, I needed to add elements dynamically in the function, so I only have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> output = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

I get an error when outputting this that:

```
error: incompatible types: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> cannot be converted to List<List<String>>
```

What is the simplest way to convert this?

Can you also explain why I need to convert in the first place? I thought that when you implement a list interface it needs to be defined by a class (linked list, arraylist,etc). So I didn't even know that you could create a `List<List<String>>.`

Comment: `arrayList.stream().<List<String>>toList()`

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` anywhere in your code, use only `List<List<String>>`

Comment: The second half of your question - why you need to do this - is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265)

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> output = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

to this:

```
List<List<String>> output = new ArrayList<>();
```

You don’t need to specify ArrayList as a variable type.  In fact, you should never specify ArrayList anywhere, except during construction.  The contract of `List` specifies all the methods you need.

Comment: The question was how to convert an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to a `List<List<String>>`.  I don't think you've answered that.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I think this is an XY problem.

Comment: Maybe, but I think it's probably better to use a comment to ask OP what they're really after, before you answer a different question from what they asked.